# Powershell xml parsing messes up the encoding

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-core

I have this very simple script:

```
$rssUrl = "https://elpais.com/rss/elpais/portada.xml"
$FeedXml = [xml](Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl)
```

At this point if I call `$FeedXml.Save()` all the accents and special caracters in the feed are messed up, as if the encoding was wrong.

For example:

```
Un periodista que viaj?? a Mil??n para
should be:
Un periodista que viajó a Milán para
```

But `(Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl).Content` produces the correct output.

I have currently done this:

```
$FeedXml = New-Object xml
$resolver = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
$resolver.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials

$reader = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
$reader.XmlResolver = $resolver
$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($rssUrl, $reader)

$FeedXml.Load($reader)
```

And on that case `$FeedXml.Save()` produces the expected output.

I have been completely unable to understand why the first code, which is supposed to be "the right way" it not working?

Comment: "all the accents and special caracters in the feed are messed up" - can you give an example of what it looks like, and what it *should* look like?

Comment: I have added the example output to the question for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the issue is that when PowerShell converts the result of `Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl` to an xml document it uses `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII` to turn the raw byte stream into a string, and in your case that's actually a utf8 byte stream according to the headers in the http request.

```
PS> $rssUrl = "https://elpais.com/rss/elpais/portada.xml"

PS> $response = Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl

PS> $response.GetType().FullName
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.BasicHtmlWebResponseObject

PS> $response.Headers["Content-Type"]
text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Here's the source for BasicHtmlWebResponseObject: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/BasicHtmlWebResponseObject.Common.cs

You can see it inherits from WebResponseObject, and the ToString method for that is here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebResponseObject.Common.cs#L88

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns the string representation of this web response.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The string representation of this web response.</returns>
public sealed override string ToString()
{
    char[] stringContent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(Content);
    //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for (int counter = 0; counter < stringContent.Length; counter++)
    {
        if (!IsPrintable(stringContent[counter]))
        {
            stringContent[counter] = '.';
        }
    }
    return new string(stringContent);
}
```

On the other hand, `(Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl).Content` is a string that has been correctly decoded using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` so it retains the accented characters.

In short, it's probably better to use `(Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl).Content` which is already a string, rather than reply on implicit conversion to a string with just `Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl`.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the detailed explanation. `$FeedXml = [xml](Invoke-WebRequest $rssUrl).Content` is all I needed and now I know why!